# What is the best word for 'search in something'?

Tags: word-choice

If I want to **search in** something like *a container*, *a chest*, or something like that, what is the best verb or word to say that ?
Thanks !

Comment: If you are looking for something in there then the most common verb is *to look*:  “I can’t find my gloves.”Did you look in that chest over there?’

Comment: And for example if I want to say something like `There is nothing to look in in this room`, is this sentence right ?

Comment: Yes. That’s fine.

Comment: If it will likely take a while for you to find what you're looking for in a container/drawers, I'd use the word "dig". Similiar to how it takes a long time to dig for gold/treasure/etc. "I will need to dig through my desk drawers to find that file."

Comment: Also, you can just say "search the chest" without the "in". For example,  "There are no containers in this room to search."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common verb for this is to [*Rummage*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=40&safe=active&site=&source=hp&q=define+rummage).

Rummaging is the act of looking through the contents of a container full of stuff, trying to find something that you know should be in there somewhere.  It implies a fairly unsystematic form of search.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I needed, thank you !